# "more of" vs "more than"

Tags: comparatives

I read a sentence somewhere:

*"To make matters worse, the power fluctuation caused two reactors at the San Onofre nuclear power station to shut down. That cut off even **more of San Diego's power supply**."*

I wonder what is the difference between **"more than San Diego's power supply"** vs **"more of San Diego's power supply"** in this same context.

more of San Diego's power supply = more power supply of San Diego ?

In **"more of San Diego's power supply"**, we use more of because of possessive adjective **"San Diego's"** before head noun. is it right?

we have the same syntax like: Give me **more candy** = give me **more of this candy**. is it right?

I hope to receive your advice. Many Thanks for your time.

Comment: I take it you meant **more than San Diego's power supply** in one of the bold alternatives?

Comment: yes, I make a mistake, "more than San Diego's power supply" vs "more of San Diego's power supply"

Comment: **Scenario 1:** "more of San Diego's power supply" = Some amount of San Diego's power supply had already been cut off before the fluctuation at the two reactors; shutting those reactors down cut off an additional amount of the city's power supply. **Scenario 2:** "more than San Diego's power supply" = Shutting down the two reactors not only cut off San Diego's power supply but also cut off power supplies to recipients outside San Diego as well. The story indicates that Scenario 1 is the case, not Scenario 2.

Comment: "Of [x]" is possessive; "than [x]" is comparative. Consider: *I have two of his games.* vs. *I have two more games than him.*

Answer (score 3):

#### 'More than' is relative, 'More of' is absolute

In your quote,

> That cut off even more of San Diego's power supply

According to [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/than), 'than' is:

> used, as after comparative adjectives and adverbs, to introduce the second member of an unequal comparison

Whereas 'of' is:

> used to indicate specific identity or a particular item within a category

Only San Diego is in the statement, and so it is not *in relation* to anything.

Since there is not a comparison between San Diego's power supply and another, 'more of' is correct.

Answer (score 0):

more than something = Another thing is greater than it.
more of something = Referring to A greater part of something.

In the upper sentence it meant that San Deigo's power supply's another part has also been cut off. While using 'more than' would mean that the cut off is more than its power supply, the limit has reached